# Declare and use a PROCEDURE IN PL-SQL block

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
PROCEDURE get_csa_type( pin_CVC_object_id     IN  NUMBER
                       ,posa_csa_type         OUT common.types.string
                       ,pona_permanent_csa    OUT common.types.string       
                      )
IS

     lc_csa_type common.types.string := 'SELECT UNIQUE csa.csa_type,csa.permanent_csa '||
    'FROM ems.ibo_sm_cvc_rfs cvc' ||
    ',ems.ibo_nbn_csa csa ' ||   
    'WHERE cvc.object_id = :1 ' ||
    'AND csa.csa_id = cvc.csa_id';
BEGIN    


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lc_csa_type BULK COLLECT INTO posa_csa_type, pona_permanent_csa
    USING pin_CVC_object_id;

END;
ls_csa_type common.types.string;
ls_permanent_csa common.types.string;
BEGIN
get_csa_type(pin_CVC_object_id => 8581213
            ,posa_csa_type => ls_csa_type
            ,pona_permanent_csa => ls_permanent_csa);
 dbms_output.put_line(ls_csa_type || ls_permanent_csa); 

END;
```

Can I declare and then call above procedure in a pl-sql block. When I try to run this I get several errors...

> Encountered the symbol "LS_CSA_TYPE" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> begin function pragma procedure
>
> Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> := . ( % ;

Comment: Yes you can. Please start e.g. from [Overview of PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS141). It explains one of the syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find here declaring the procedure and executing it in the block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move variables declarations at the begining, before subprocedure. Similar code below worked for me:

```
DECLARE
  ls_csa_type varchar2(4000);
  ls_permanent_csa varchar2(4000);

  PROCEDURE get_csa_type( pin_CVC_object_id     IN  NUMBER
                         ,posa_csa_type         OUT varchar2
                         ,pona_permanent_csa    OUT varchar2 ) IS
      lc_csa_type varchar2(4000) := 'SELECT dummy, dummy from dual where 1 = :1 ';
  BEGIN    
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lc_csa_type 
      INTO posa_csa_type, pona_permanent_csa
      USING pin_CVC_object_id;
  END get_csa_type;

BEGIN
  get_csa_type(pin_CVC_object_id => 1
              ,posa_csa_type => ls_csa_type
              ,pona_permanent_csa => ls_permanent_csa);
  dbms_output.put_line(ls_csa_type || ls_permanent_csa); 
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me, but I think you skipped "declare" in your executing block:

```
**declare**
ls_csa_type common.types.string;
ls_permanent_csa common.types.string;
BEGIN
get_csa_type(pin_CVC_object_id => 8581213
            ,posa_csa_type => ls_csa_type
            ,pona_permanent_csa => ls_permanent_csa)
 dbms_output.put_line(ls_csa_type || ls_permanent_csa); 

END;
```

Comment: I have declare on the second line in my question code, if I put it before declaring the 2 variables will thorw this error: `Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"`

Comment: Hmm, are you sure?? Added the second declare but still getting the same error, updated the question as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

In this row

```
END get_csa_type;
```

remove get_csa_type:

```
END;
```

Also after this row you must have a separator `;`:

```
get_csa_type(pin_CVC_object_id => 8581213
            ,posa_csa_type => ls_csa_type
            ,pona_permanent_csa => ls_permanent_csa);
```

Comment: Updated the code in the question, still, getting `Encountered the symbol "LS_CSA_TYPE" when expecting one of the following:begin function pragma procedure`